# Original Russian text of this review of Crime and Punishment

Tags: russian-language, quote-source, fyodor-dostoyevsky, crime-and-punishment

In the introduction to Constance Garnett's translation of Crime and Punishment, she quotes this Russian critic:

> In the words of a Russian critic, who seeks to explain the feeling
> inspired by Dostoevsky: "He was one of ourselves, a man of our blood
> and our bone, but one who has suffered and has seen so much more
> deeply than we have his insight impresses us as wisdom... that wisdom
> of the heart which we seek that we may learn from it how to live. All
> his other gifts came to him from nature, this he won for himself and
> through it he became great."

Can someone help me find the original Russian text of this critical review? I would like to memorize it, because it echoes my feelings about Dostoevsky when I first read him in English.

Comment: There's no reason to expect this quote to come from a review of *Crime and Punishment* in particular. Garnett's "Translator's Preface" was printed in several of her translations, for example [here it is](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.499318/page/n5/mode/2up) in a Heinemann edition of *The Brothers Karamazov*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I googled for "мудрость сердца" (the wisdom of the heart) and "достоевский" and found a book "Fedor Mikhailovich Dostoevsky. His life and works" (comp. V. Pokrovsky), and there is the quote you search.

[image: Screenshot from Google Books]

It is written though in 19th century Russian and my interpretation goes like:

> Кого потеряла Россия в нем? Проще всего будет сказать, что **это был один из нас, от нашей кости и плоти человек, но так неизмеримо больше нас переживший, так в неизмеримо большее прозревший, что это прозрение естественно представляется нам как мудрость;** не та мудрость, что составляет плодь умственных в[ы]кладов, и которую мы любим как предмет любопытства, но не считаем ее достаточно сериозною, что бы по ней жить, - но **мудрость сердца, которой мы ищем именно для того, чтобы научиться, как жить. Все другие дары дала ему природа, - этот он приобрел и им стал велик.** / B. Розанов /

<sub>The quote in the question highlighted here in bold</sub>

The man who wrote it is [Vasily Vasilievich Rozanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Rozanov), Russian critic and writer.

Comment: I tip my hat in awe. As much as I tried, I couldn't find the source myself.